# How to quickly edit vim variable content?

Tags: variables

In vim I sometimes want to quickly change the content of a variable using its current content as template using vim editing capabilities.

For example I want to append the word "bar" to the existing variable `myvar`.

```
let myvar="foo"
```

A possible workflow could be a ex-command (say `Edit`) editing myvar in a new buffer with "foo" as its contend and upon saving the buffer it would overwrite the new content (i.e. "foo bar") to the variable:

```
:Edit myvar
```

I feel there must be an elegant solution, possibly even another workflow than the one outlined above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've picked an unfortunate example, as it's more easily achieved with:

```
let myvar .= 'bar'
```

Still, for more complicated edits, you could use the following commands:

1. Insert the variable into the buffer:

   ```
   o<C-R>=myvar<CR>
   ```

   N.B. In the above, `<C-R>` denotes a press of <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, and `<CR>` is a press of <kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. Perform your edits.
3. Reassign the contents of the line to the variable and delete the line:

   ```
   :let myvar = getline('.') | d
   ```

Steps 1 & 3 can be converted into mappings:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <leader>ev "o\<C-R>=" . input('Variable: ', 'myvar', 'var') . "\<CR>"
:nnoremap <expr> <leader>av ':let ' . input('Variable: ', 'myvar', 'var') . " = getline('.') <bar> d\<CR>"
```

These prompt the user for which variable they want to edit/assign to, offering a default of `myvar`, and using `variable` completion so you don't have to type out the whole variable name.

If you *always* want to edit `myvar`, you can just replace the call to `input()` with `myvar`. If you only want to be asked in the *first* mapping, then you could save the name of the variable selected in a variable and use that in the second mapping: at that point you'd probably be better off using a mapping that calls a function instead of attempting to cram it into a one-liner.

Creating a more polished, complete solution as described in the question is left as an exercise to the reader. You'd probably want to set up a function to create the new buffer and insert the contents of the variable, and a `BufWriteCmd` autocommand to intercept the saving of that buffer (and *only* that buffer) and instead reassign to the variable.

Further reading:

- `:help i_CTRL-R_=`
- `:help getline()`
- `:help :d`
- `:help :map-expr`
- `:help input()`
- `:help :command-completion`
- `:help :function`
- `:help autocommand`
- `:help Cmd-event`

Comment: I've accepted this solutions since extensively elaborated, adaptable and doesn't require a plugin (which I prefer). I agree, the example was somewhat unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin [editvar](https://github.com/thinca/vim-editvar) does this.  Just use `:Editvar myvar`, where `myvar` is a variable.  This opens a window with the variable's contents.  You can type `:w` to update the variable value.